# How do I avoid infinite adding on array on rerender with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am setting the initial state in redux with

```
      useEffect(() => {
        data?.map((user) =>
          dispatch(
            addUser({
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              username: user.username,
              email: user.email,
              address: {
                city: user.address.city,
              },
            })
          )
        );
      }, [data, dispatch]);
```

which dispatches

```
    addUser(state, action: PayloadAction<User>) {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    },
```

The thing is that every time the component rerenders, the same items are added to the array. I know why it happens, but I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone help, please?
data is fetched from an api

Comment: Do you get `data` from redux selector?

Comment: @nosnart sorry I forgot to mention, I fetch the data from an api

Comment: @Gass I have. Nothing is added if it's empty

Comment: @illyria probably cause you concat data to existing state. Try to return state = action.payload

Comment: @nosnart it doesn't work. I am just getting the last fetched item

Comment: sorry ^^ map through the data and dispatch **addUser** at once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242629/discussion-between-illyria-and-nos-nart).

Comment: When you need to fetch data once, you don't need  to pass `data` again as `useEffect` dependency

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel I tried to remove it, but it's just empty then

Comment: Try to pass dependencies as `[data.length, dispatch]`

Comment: @BYIRINGIROEmmanuel I solved this problem, but now it resets the array to the initialstate even after I add items to it

Comment: Glad to hear that